# Create two indexes at same time

Tags: indexing, sas

Is It possible to create more than one index at same time on SAS data step?

I have the follow

```
DATA DADOS;
    INFILE DATALINES DELIMITER=',';
    INPUT SETOR $ DIRETORIA $ 13.;
    DATALINES;
    SETOR1,DIRETORIA1
    SETOR1,DIRETORIA2
    SETOR2,DIRETORIA1
    SETOR2,DIRETORIA2
    SETOR2,DIRETORIA4
    SETOR3,DIRETORIA4
    SETOR4,DIRETORIA2
    SETOR5,DIRETORIA2
    SETOR5,DIRETORIA3
;RUN;
```

Then I need to add two indexes, one for column SETOR and anoother for DIRETORIA LIKE this

| SETOR | DIRETORIA | SETOR_ID | DIRETORIA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SETOR1 | DIRETORIA1 | 1 | 1 |
| SETOR1 | DIRETORIA2 | 1 | 2 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA1 | 2 | 1 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA2 | 2 | 2 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA3 | 2 | 3 |
| SETOR3 | DIRETORIA4 | 3 | 4 |
| SETOR4 | DIRETORIA2 | 4 | 2 |
| SETOR5 | DIRETORIA2 | 5 | 2 |
| SETOR5 | DIRETORIA3 | 5 | 3 |

I've tried this, but don't work.

```
DATA DETALHE_1;
    SET DADOS;

    BY SETOR DIRETORIA;

    RETAIN SETOR_ID DIRETORIA_ID;

    IF FIRST.SETOR THEN 
        SETOR_ID + 1;

    IF FIRST.DIRETORIA THEN 
        DIRETORIA_ID + 1;
RUN;
```

And what i got

| SETOR | DIRETORIA | SETOR_ID | DIRETORIA_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SETOR1 | DIRETORIA1 | 1 | 1 |
| SETOR1 | DIRETORIA2 | 1 | 2 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA1 | 2 | 3 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA2 | 2 | 4 |
| SETOR2 | DIRETORIA3 | 2 | 5 |
| SETOR3 | DIRETORIA4 | 3 | 6 |
| SETOR4 | DIRETORIA2 | 4 | 7 |
| SETOR5 | DIRETORIA2 | 5 | 8 |
| SETOR5 | DIRETORIA3 | 5 | 9 |

The SETOR_ID is correct, but DIRETORIA_ID don't.

How to solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't a way to do both of these at once, since you need the data sorted differently so you'll need separate steps.  FYI - SAS has an Index function, as well as indexes on data set. I'd probably try and use a different term if possible.

Comment: Those are not indexes (in any sense of the word).  Looks you are are trying create a numeric surrogate for the character variables.  You could do that with hash objects (if the number of levels are small enough that they can fit in memory).  Why do you want the numeric surrogate values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks to me like you just want to count, not index in any sense of the word.

You are counting setor across the whole dataset and diretoria within the current value of setor.  Your sample data does not have any repeating values of diretoria, but let's code so that if you did then each distinct value within the given value of sector would be assigned the same count id.

```
data want;
  set DADOS;
  by setor diretoria;
  setor_id + first.setor;
  diretoria_id + first.diretoria;
  if first.setor then diretoria_id=1;
run;
```

Results

```
                                           diretoria_
Obs    SETOR     DIRETORIA     setor_id        id

 1     SETOR1    DIRETORIA1        1            1
 2     SETOR1    DIRETORIA2        1            2
 3     SETOR2    DIRETORIA1        2            1
 4     SETOR2    DIRETORIA2        2            2
 5     SETOR2    DIRETORIA4        2            3
 6     SETOR3    DIRETORIA4        3            1
 7     SETOR4    DIRETORIA2        4            1
 8     SETOR5    DIRETORIA2        5            1
 9     SETOR5    DIRETORIA3        5            2
10     SETOR5    DIRETORIA3        5            2
```

If you need to assign each value of diretoria the same number across the different values of setor then you would need a different method.  One that could keep track of which values of diretoria have been already assigned a number.  Such as by building a HASH object. In which case the data need not be sorted by either variable, but the number of distinct setor and diretoria values would need to be able to fit into memory.

```
data want ;
  set dados;
  if _n_=1 then do;
    declare hash s();
    declare hash d();
    _rc=s.definekey('setor');
    _rc=d.definekey('diretoria');
    _rc=s.definedata('setor_id');
    _rc=d.definedata('diretoria_id');
    _rc=s.definedone();
    _rc=d.definedone();
  end;
  if s.find() then do; _setor+1; setor_id=_setor; _rc=s.add(); end;
  if d.find() then do; _diretoria+1; diretoria_id=_diretoria; _rc=d.add();  end;
  drop _:;
run;
```

Results:

```
                                           diretoria_
Obs    SETOR     DIRETORIA     setor_id        id

  1    SETOR1    DIRETORIA1        1            1
  2    SETOR1    DIRETORIA2        1            2
  3    SETOR2    DIRETORIA1        2            1
  4    SETOR2    DIRETORIA2        2            2
  5    SETOR2    DIRETORIA4        2            3
  6    SETOR3    DIRETORIA4        3            3
  7    SETOR4    DIRETORIA2        4            2
  8    SETOR5    DIRETORIA2        5            2
  9    SETOR5    DIRETORIA3        5            4
 10    SETOR5    DIRETORIA3        5            4
```

Comment: New stuff for me :)  I didn't know this hash aproach. Thank @Tom.

Comment: Minor point: You don't need work variables `_setor` or `_directoria` because the new ids can be computed as `setor_id=s.num_items+1` or `directoria_id=d.num_items+1`